# Binding to global event using Spine & jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, events, spine.js

I'm trying out Spine.js for the first time and I'm currently converting an existing js file that uses jQuery.

It currently does something like this:

```
$('document').bind('facebook:ready', function () {
    $('.myElement').click(callback);
});
```

Where it basically waits for the 'facebook:ready' event to be triggered on the document and then attaches an onclick to .myElement.

So far, I've been able to do regular events by following the documentation for Controllers, http://spinejs.com/docs/controllers

```
myController = Spine.Controller.sub({
    el: $('#mainViewElement')
    , events: hashOfEventsToNamesAndHandler
});
```

What is the right way to convert the old code to Spine?  And, as a related question, since I have a global object that I use for namespacing, would it be better to attach my 'facebook:ready' event to that instead of document?

---

One thing I was thinking was I could have a flag that gets set when 'facebook:ready' fires.  Then I attach the click handler to .myElement using the normal Spine.Controller syntax and when the click gets triggered I check to see if that flag was set, if not I return immediately.   I'm just not sure if this is the best way to go about this though...

Answer (score 1):

The facebook:ready event is something that happens out of Spine so you won't be able to handle it with an events hash. The actions in an events hash are scoped to the element that controller is active on.

In Spine you're not limited to the events attributes. You could use whatever you want. The events hash is only a shortcut. To set up more complex stuff you could do something in the constructor.

I don't know the hierarchy of your app and how many controllers would need to update itself when the facebook event fires. But let's assume that only one controller will monitor for it and that it informs others of what just happened... in case some other logic needs to be triggered.

```
class FacebookIntegrationController extends Spine.Controller

  constructor: ->
    super

    # You can't use $ here because that is scoped to the current @el. So use the jQuery object itself.
    # What I would suggest is to just trigger a local action.
    jQuery('document').bind('facebook:ready', @facebookReady())

  facebookReady: (argument) =>
    # Here you can just handle it however you would like.

    # This works if .myElement is somewhere in the @el of this controller. But it isn't the nicest solution.
    $('.myElement').click(callback)

    # Instead write the code that's in the callback in this function. Or if the callback is passed along with the original event you can get to it as the arguments are passed along to the function (argument in this case).

    # If multiple controllers need to take action after the facebook:ready event has fired in the document you could also trigger a new event:
    @trigger('facebook:ready') # You could add optional arguments to trigger that get passed along to the functions that bind to it.

    # Other controllers or other Spine classes could listen for it by using:
    # FacebookIntegrationController.bind('facebook:ready', @localActionToTrigger)
    # If this doesn't work nicely for you you could also use global events by replacing @trigger with Spine.trigger and Spine.bind('facebook:ready', @localActionToTrigger)
```

Untested code!!
edit: implemented code: http://jsfiddle.net/SpoBo/zAwKk/3/

Apologies for the CoffeeScriptness of my code. It's really worth learning especially because you can learn a lot from the Spine source.

Comment: thanks for the help @SpoBo...while I was able to resolve it by using a flag and just returning from the event if the flag was set, this helps me better understand how MVC could be used (I'm new to MVC)...Its not totally clear at the moment, however, and I think I just need to let this sink in...

Comment: I could also have explained it badly :pAlex Mccaw's book on javascript apps might help you though. http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920018421.do

Comment: Best advice is to just dig in and try to understand everything you see. Don't blindly trust the scaffolding code (in fact, don't use it at all). Learn what everything does and ask why and how it does it. I also dabbled in backbone and imho spine is much easier to understand.

Comment: yeah thanks...luckily I read his book just recently, otherwise I would be completely lost!  What do you mean by scaffolding code?

Comment: You are not using something like rails-spine or some other tool that can generate a bunch of models and controllers based on some input? Best not to do something like that but to write everything by hand at first. I made a jsfiddle for our question. New to that platform, so was fun to try this out :p http://jsfiddle.net/SpoBo/zAwKk/3/ This is how I envision it working. The LoggingController is optional but Spine.trigger & Spine.bind connect the 2.